# How to send data about connect and disconnect from the server

Tags: reactjs, websocket, socket.io, nestjs

I am creating a real-time chat in which I would like to display the number of users who have a page open
I know that the handleConnection method shows the ID of the connected. And handle Disconnection for those who disconnected, how can you create an array where all users of the site will be and send it

```
import {
  MessageBody,
  SubscribeMessage,
  WebSocketGateway,
  OnGatewayInit,
  WebSocketServer,
  OnGatewayConnection,
  OnGatewayDisconnect,
} from '@nestjs/websockets';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Socket, Server } from 'socket.io';

@WebSocketGateway(8001, { cors: '*' })
export class ChatGateway
  implements OnGatewayInit, OnGatewayConnection, OnGatewayDisconnect
{
  @WebSocketServer() server: Server;
  private logger: Logger = new Logger('AppGateway');
  @SubscribeMessage('message')
  handleMessage(@MessageBody() message: string): void {
    console.log(message);
    this.server.emit('message', message);
  }

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    this.logger.log(server);
  }
  handleDisconnect(client: Socket) {
    this.logger.log(`Client disconnected: ${client.id}`);
  }

  handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
   this.logger.log(`Client connected: ${client.id}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that the connection goes not to the page, but to the server. On the client, I connect to the server

Comment: I would like to display on my client the number of users who have connected to the server

Comment: have you try `const numberOfConnection = (await this.server.allSockets()).size` in your handleConnection?

Comment: @webdev_jj It helped. In the console I see the number of connected users.
How can I now send this data to frontend?
So?     return this.server.emit(numberOfConnection);

Comment: it depends on how your frontend expecting to receive the data. For example, if your frontend listening to a specific event say 'connection-count-changed' event, then you need to emit this event with updated count every time a new connection connected/disconnected.